# String class in C++

Tags: c++, string

If I were to access the `char *` array inside a string, do the arrays include spaces?

Example.

```
String s = "1 3";
```

Would `s[1]` be `" "` or `3`?

Thank you!

Comment: C++ doesn't have a class called `String`; C++ has `std::string` (note the lower-case). Are you using some other programming language, or did you really mean `std::string = "1 3";`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it includes spaces. `s[1]` is `' '`.

Spaces are characters as any other.

Answer (score 9):

Yes they do.

```
s[0] == '1';
s[1] == ' '; // equals 32 ascii
s[2] == '3';
```

It is zero-indexed array with starting element of 0 and ending element of n-1.
Also note that s[1] is not `" "` (double quotes) but `' '` (single quotes) because single quotes indicate character literal.

Comment: Assuming he is using `std::string`, `s[3]` is undefined, not necessarily `'\0'`.

Comment: @MagnusHoff, true if access is using `operator []`. If he really wants to "access the char * array inside a string" then official interface is `string::c_str()`, which is guaranteed to be null terminated.

Comment: @thekashyap: I'd prefer `data()`, which is the most direct interface for accessing the underlying `char*` as I understand it.

Comment: @celtschk : What do you mean by "official"? Both `c_str` and `data` are standardized, and further, in C++11 they are guaranteed to return the same value (i.e., always null-terminated).

Comment: @ildjarn That hasn't always been the case has it?

Comment: @ildjarn: My comment referred to an earlier version of Magnus Hoff's comment where he wrote "official" instead of "direct". That's also why I deleted it: It didn't any longer fit to the current verson of the comment I answered. You managed to read it in the short window between creation and deletion due to obsoleteness. And yes, both are official, that was my point. I didn't know that data zero-terminates, are you sure about that? I though they added a different function exactly to avoid the zero termination of c_str; otherwise, what would be the point in having two different methods?

Comment: @Lou : No, in C++98/03, `data` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, only `c_str` is; in C++11, both have that guarantee.

Comment: @celtschk : Ah, apologies, I didn't notice that you subsequently deleted your comment. In any case, yes, in C++11 `data` is guaranteed to return the exact same value as `c_str`. The purpose of having two different methods at this point is simply to retain backwards-compatibility.

Comment: Thanks all, I totally forgot abt `data()`.. :).. My use of word "official" was wrong.